# How to track joints with multiple Kinects at the same time?

Tags: c#, kinect, tracking

I am writing a code to track coordinates of all joints of the skeleton with two Kinects. This is the code I have so far. It writes out the coordinates of the joints to console per frame. However it only does so for the second Kinect. I am missing something really simple from the code to make if print to console for two Kinects, but I cannot figure it out.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectedSensors = new List<KinectSensor>();
        int sensors = 0;
        foreach(KinectSensor sensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors){
            if (sensor == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Kinect sensor connected :(");
                return;
            }
            connectedSensors.Add(sensor);
            sensors += 1;

        }
        foreach(KinectSensor s in connectedSensors){
            Tracker tracker = new Tracker(s, sensors);
            s.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
            s.Start();
            while (Char.ToLowerInvariant(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) != 'q') { }
            s.Stop();
        }
    }
}

class Tracker
{
    private int skeletonId;
    private Skeleton[] skeletons;
    public Tracker(KinectSensor sensor, int sensorNr)
    {
        skeletonId = sensorNr;
        sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += SensorSkeletonFrameReady;
        sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
    }


    private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (skeletonFrame != null)
            {
                if (this.skeletons == null)
                {
                    this.skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                }
                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(this.skeletons);
                Skeleton skeleton = this.skeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked).FirstOrDefault();
                if (skeleton != null)
                {
                    foreach (Joint j in skeleton.Joints)
                    {
                        if (j.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked || j.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Inferred)
                            Console.WriteLine("SENSOR "+ skeletonId +"\t "+j.JointType + "\t " + j.Position.X + "\t " + j.Position.Y + "\t " + j.Position.Z);
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("SENSOR " + skeletonId + "\t " + j.JointType + "\t 0\t 0\t 0");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop

```
foreach(KinectSensor s in connectedSensors)
{
   Tracker tracker = new Tracker(s, sensors);
   s.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
   s.Start();
   while (Char.ToLowerInvariant(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) != 'q') { }
   s.Stop();
}
```

starts the first sensor, waits for you to press "q" and stops the first sensor. Than the second sensor is started. Is that what you want?

If you want to run both sensors at the same time, you should try something like to following:

```
foreach(KinectSensor s in connectedSensors)
{
   Tracker tracker = new Tracker(s, sensors);
   s.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
   s.Start();
}
while (Char.ToLowerInvariant(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) != 'q') { }
foreach(KinectSensor s in connectedSensors)
{
   s.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sensors constructor argument you are passing is always going to be the number for the last sensor:

```
 Tracker tracker = new Tracker(s, sensors);
```

You need use another variable in your loop or use a regular for loop:

```
   for(int i=0; i < sensors; i += 1){
        KinectSensor s = connectedSensors[i];
        Tracker tracker = new Tracker(s, i); //the second parameter here is the one you needed to fix.
        s.SkeletonStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
        s.Start();
        while (Char.ToLowerInvariant(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar) != 'q') { }
        s.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: This is all true, however only one sensor activates, the last one and changing this index does not affect it.

Comment: sorry, can't help with the sensor not activating